Pandas column value -5 to -$5
How to convert value to add $ symbol. If value is 6 then it should be $6, if the value is -6 then it should be -$6.
I have not tried anything
How to convert value to add $ symbol. If value is 6 then it should be $6, if the value is -6 then it should be -$6.
I have not tried anything

import pandas as pd

def add_dollar_sign(value):
    if pd.isna(value):
        return value
    elif value >= 0:
        return f"${value}"
    else:
        return f"-${abs(value)}"

# Example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Number': [5, -5, 10, -3, 0]})

# Apply the add_dollar_sign function to the 'Number' column
df['Number'] = df['Number'].apply(add_dollar_sign)

print(df)

Output:
  Number
0     $5
1    -$5
2    $10
3    -$3
4     $0

